# Pytube AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span'

Tags: python, error-handling, pytube

Hi I have a problem with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'span' I read on the StackOverflow a channel with this problem on this I found the potential solution but it still not working here was a advice to change a

this:

```
152: func_regex = re.compile(r"function\([^)]+\)")
```

to this

```
152: func_regex = re.compile(r"function\([^)]?\)")
```

but it is not working and I do not know how to solute it because A youtube Stil upgrading a platform and this error will be probably in the future too.

So I can Ask is some other method to download a youtube video.

```
from pytube.__main__ import YouTube 
from pytube.streams import Stream
def downloadVideo(link):
    
    video = pytube.YouTube(link)
    
    video.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
    
    try:
      os.rename(video.streams.get_highest_resolution().default_filename, word +".mp4")

    except Exception:
        print("Expection in renamed file ")
```

Sorry for the bad indentation but the os.rename ... is too long for write it here

Comment: A [mre] would be needed for anyone to be able to even try to help you. Please see the [tour] and the [ask] page, and the [help], for further clarification on what is required in questions on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pytube/cipher.py on line 293, change the line:

```
    name = re.escape(get_throttling_function_name(js))
```

to

```
    name = "iha"
```

Answered by czarnoff on the pytube github. If you have any bugs with pytube, I would recommend you check the issues section on the pytube github because bugs get fixed there the fastest.